# IF user Role / Family equal to?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three tables `Users`, `UsersInFamily`, `Familys`.

I would like to be able to check if a user is attached to a family name. Similar to the way you can check users are in roles i.e `User.IsInRole("Admin")`. I would like to be able to do something like the below but I cant see how to achieve this (I'm a novice so forgive me please!):

```
var user = context.Users.Where(c => c.UserID == FormPostID).SingleOrDefault();

if (user.Familys.FamilyName == "Flinstone") // Can't seem to get the family name
```

I was thinking I might need to write a function `GetFamilyForUser(UserID);` to compare against but was hoping I could do something like the above?

Essential I would like to check users are in a `Family` and are in a `Role` of editor before they can make a edit.

Kinda like the Mafia, Only when you have been made a made man in the family can you have a opinion lol!

Comment: Hi! is it give you some error? What's happend? Cause the code looks ok...

Comment: The EF pluralizer probably knows that Family -> Families, so you may be accessing something that doesn't exist.  Also string comparison I'm used to writing as "Flinstone".Equals(user.Families.FamilyName) but that might just be a stylistic holdover from my Java days, and not a problem in C#.

Comment: I just wanted to agree with Mikeb, the property is probably called "user.Family.FamilyName"

Comment: I get user.Familys but can't get user.Familys.FamilyName? I was thinking of assigning user.Familys to a list or a array or something and attempting to query the family name from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your database design properly, UsersInFamily should contain UserID and FamilyID fields, right, so that multiple users could be members of multiple families?

If that is the case, you can't do that the way you tried. You need to call this instead:

```
var user = context.UsersInFamily.Where(c => c.UserID == FormPostID).SingleOrDefault(); 
if (user.Familys.FamilyName == "Flinstone") 
{
    // This should work
}
```

However, if the relation between Users and Familys tables is many-to-one, then you would need to call this instead:

```
var user = context.Users.Where(c => c.UserID == FormPostID).SingleOrDefault(); 
foreach (Family f in user.Familys)
{
    if (f.FamilyName == "Flintstone")
    {
        // This works
    }
}
```